# How can I convert the date format dynamically?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can I convert the date format dynamically?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the demo page (You *really* should have done that first) : http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", THEDATEFORMATYOUWANT);
```